# RF disturbances produced by transmission power lines

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, resource-recommendations, radio-frequency

I need a book or paper that contains "the effects of transmission lines on the radio frequency transmission and disturbances". 
Could you help me find a useful textbook?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here is a link to a paper by Patrick C. Crane on the transmission line disturbances to RF: http://www.faculty.ece.vt.edu/swe/lwa/memo/lwa0168.pdf.  I didn't read the paper, but it seems to be an extensive analysis, and mentions at least 3 other references on the subject.

   On page 3, you'll find a summary of effects on three types of RF:

   > The phenomena associated with corona have been described quantitatively by Chartier (1983): radio noise (RI) over the frequency range 0.1-20 MHz (i.e., AM radio, ham radio); television interference (TVI) over the frequency range 10-1000 MHz, which includes VHF and UHF television and FM radio and, coincidentally, is measured in the radio-astronomy allocation 73.0-74.6 MHz…
2. Another source is the textbook [Electric Power Generation, Transmission and Distribution](https://books.google.com/books?id=XMl8OU4wIEQC&pg=SA19-PA14&lpg=SA19-PA14&dq=textbook+on+disturbances+caused+by+electric+transmission+lines&source=bl&ots=6Tz7fkcf4L&sig=NWInuuoJzim0GFgKHzEyx_znrps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwA2oVChMIvqDBw9bKxwIVgjU-Ch1YfQN3#v=onepage&q=textbook%20on%20disturbances%20caused%20by%20electric%20transmission%20lines&f=false)  The linked page (from Google Books) includes a list of references on electromagnetic interference.
3. The consulting firm Kevin Kennedy Associates website has an [Opinion On The Impact Of High-Voltage Power Lines On Communication Services](http://www.kevinkennedyassociates.com/opinion-on-the-impact-of-high-voltage-power-lines-on-communication-services/).  But this opinion is not a peer-reviewed paper.  Here are the conclusions:

   > 1. The 60-Hz electromagnetic waves radiated by the power line are weak because of the inherent cancellation of waves generated by individual phase currents.
   > 2. For a power line acting as an effective antenna for 60-Hz waves, it would have to be 2,500 km long.
   > 3. Harmonic pollution of the national grid may result in electromagnetic interference within the frequency spectrum up to 1 MHz. Thus, a “static” can be heard on a car radio when passing a power line as the AM stations operate in the general area of that frequency. However, the cell-phone networks utilize narrow bands of the frequency spectrum near 0.9 GHz and 1.9 GHz. Respective values for the wireless Internet are 2.4 GHz and 5.8 GHz. Thus, the noise generated by the power line occupies a place in the frequency spectrum that is extremely distant from spectral locations of the said communication services.
   > 4. Inductance of the wires in the power line have the low-pass filtering effect on currents, drastically reducing those of high-frequency content.
   > 5. In contrast to the radio, today’s cell-phone and wireless Internet services are provided in the digital rather than analog format, which greatly reduced the vulnerability to external interferences.

I don't know how reliable these conclusions are, as their work is not available online.